# DC motor control ULN2803

Tags: dc, pwm, dc-motor, esp8266

I'm trying to do some basic DC motor (pump) control through an [Adafruit Feather Huzzah](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821) (ESP8266) and an [ULN2803](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2803a.pdf) Darlington transistor array; I've wired it up as follows:

[image]

And my code goes a little something like this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(14, 0);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available())
  {
    int speed = Serial.parseInt();
    if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 1023)
    {
      analogWrite(14, speed);
      Serial.print("PWM set to ");
      Serial.println(speed);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, unless `analogWrite()` is set to 1023, the motor only humms and does not rotate.

What I've done to troubleshoot:

- I've used a (cheap) voltmeter to validate that the voltage going to
  the motor is variable as I adjust the `analogWrite()` value.
- Also, I've replaced the motor with a LED strip and it fades properly as I adjust the `analogWrite()` value.
- Finally, I've hooked the motor up to a desktop power supply, and was
  able to validate that as I reduce the voltage from 12V to 0V, the
  motor slows down.

What am I missing?

Comment: It doesn't rotate even at analogWrite(14, 1022)? Note that "analogWrite" gives a PWM output, ***not*** an analog voltage from 0V to 12V as you simulated with your desktop supply.

Comment: I never tried 1022, but at 800 it wouldn't rotate.  I understand that the analogWrite gives a PWM output, that's why I've got it hooked up to the ULN2803. :)

Comment: Oh, ok. It could be that voltage drop + lower duty cycle is not enough to start your motor. Depending on your motor current the voltage drop can get up to 1.5V. Is it possible to check if you can reliably start the motor at ~10V on your bench supply? p.s.: try adding a >100uF cap on the breadboard as close as possible to motor + buffer

Comment: That was it @WesleyLee - the starting V wasn't high enough to get the rotor spinning.  I've added an answer to be clear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WesleyLee got me on the right track; it looks like the starting voltage has to be high enough to get the motor spinning (at least initially).

The sketch below will get the motor running at a very low voltage:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  analogWrite(14, 1023);
  delay(15);
  analogWrite(14, 200);
  delay(3000);
}
```

It's not a beautiful solution but I suppose it works for my application.  That's what you get for buying cheap pumps I guess.

Comment: Shouldnt it be 1023 instead of 1024? :P

Answer (score 0):

Measure the Motor coil resistance or Coil voltage when ON.

The semiconductor switch must be much lower ESR than the DCR coil resistance.

The ULN 2803 is approximately 1.7Ω so if your Motor DCR is in the low Ω range it won't work at all then you need a logic level MOSFET switch with RdsOn << 10% of the motor DCR contact resistance measured with a DMM.  ( preferably < 2% of DCR to reduce heating.

The motor impedance increases 5~10x with full speed motion from back EMF.

Please report back DCR values.

Notice below using two Darlingtons in parallel improves a lot, but not quite 1/2.
[image]
MOSFET switches are a much better solution but cost more.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I haven't been able to measure the DCR coil resistance but was able to find a solution (work around) - see my answer.

Comment: Ah yes pump over the stall speed.